# What event can I hook into upon RequestNavigate to userControl?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, prism-4

I have a view in a WPF application I'm writing using PRISM & Unity for IOC/DI. Upon the entering of details in a client view I save details to database then call my regionManagers' requestNavigate to my main client view. I want to call my RefreshDetails command everytime my ClientView is navigated to, what event on my ClientMainView userControl can I hook into to bind to my RefreshDetails command?

Answer (score 0):

I bound to my userControls' Loaded event like so:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RefreshDetailsCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and my command fires....